# Can an ArrayList made using a constructor from a class be saved to SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android

So I am making a simple wine list app. There are three main activities.

1. MainActivity - this is where the list of wines is, along with a FAB that takes you to the AddWineActivity. Each list item on this page only shows a thumbnail, the wine name, price, and rating.
2. AddWineActivity - has a couple of EditTexts (to get the wine's name, price, and description), a ratingbar (to get the wine rating), and a button that converts the details into strings and puts them into into intent extras.
3. WineDetailsActivity - This will have a nice page that has all of the details for the wine in the list you clicked on.

---

I have the app pretty much working how I want it to currently. The only thing is that I need to actually save the list of wines so it wont reset after you go back in to add another wine, or if you leave the app and come back.

Here is the tricky part (which doesn't help since I don't know too much about saving to device anyway yet). I am adding to the arraylist using a Class.

I have a Wine class that has a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Wine(String mWineName, String mWinePrice, String mWineRating, String mWineDescription, int mWineImageResourceID) {}
```

So then on the **MainActivity**, to add to the list it looks like this

```
wines.add(new Wine(getIntent().getStringExtra("WINENAME"), getIntent().getStringExtra("WINEPRICE"), getIntent().getStringExtra("WINERATING"), getIntent().getStringExtra("WINEDESCRIPTION"), R.drawable.mywinelogo));
```

---

What would be the recommended way to add a list that looks like that to the device? Would it still be shared preferences or am I not on the right track?

If more details about the app are wanted, just ask for them and I'll provide them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the recommended way to add a list that looks like that to the device? Would it still be shared preferences or am I not on the right track?

In the end, you have a tabular data structure: rows (wines) and columns (name, rating, etc.).

When you have a tabular data structure, save it to something that is table-friendly. That could be a SQLite database or some form of file (e.g., JSON, XML).

`SharedPreferences` is not well-suited for this. You could convert the table to JSON and store it as a string preference, but that's relatively uncommon. IMHO, that would only make sense if most of the rest of your data were more natural for `SharedPreferences` (e.g., you were using `PreferenceScreen` to collect them) and wanted to keep everything together.